# Can there be bad unions?

Tags: plumbing, pipe

1 inch brass union continues to leak with proper pressure and pipe dope.  Is the union bad?  How do I check?

Comment: Were is it leaking from?? Sweated or threaded?

Comment: Of course there can be a bad union, it could have a pinhole in it or the threads could be defective.  But the chances are very high that it's an installation problem, not a material defect.

Comment: The unions that I have used are metal on metal, no pipe dope.

Comment: Are you sure the union is leaking from the union proper, and not from one of the threaded or soldered attaches to the union?